# if function in R

Tags: r, function

I am quite new in R. I have two set of data.
I have labeled them as "outlier" when the difference exceeds a certain threshold.
Now, I would like to make a function which subtract the row of Table_1 column from Table_2 where label is "outlier" in the Result column.

Code:

```
errorr <- data.frame(Table_1=unname(x.fore$pred), Table_2=unname(rn25_29_t$ambtemp))
errorr <- transform(errorr, Result = ifelse(Table_1 - 0.3 < Table_2 & Table_2 < Table_1 + 0.3, 'Normal', 'Outlier'))
```

Sample data:

```
   Table_1 Table_2  Result
1 5.778986    5.58  Normal
2 5.768515    6.50 Outlier
3 5.758068    5.83  Normal
4 5.747644    5.54  Normal
5 5.737245    5.80  Normal
6 5.726869    6.03 Outlier
```

Expected result:

```
5.768515 -  6.50 = -0.731485
5.726869 -  6.03 = -0.303131
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, maybe (although the output is less pretty)

```
diff(t(dat[dat$Result == "Outlier", 2:1]))
##                 2         6
## Table_1 -0.731485 -0.303131
```

Answer (score 3):

If `dat` is the dataset

```
 indx <- dat$Result=="Outlier"
 dat[indx,1]-dat[indx,2]
 #[1] -0.731485 -0.303131
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work also, and it's a little faster. `ifelse` is rather slow.  Vector indexing is much faster.

```
> with(dat, (Table_1 - Table_2)[Result == "Outlier"])
# [1] -0.731485 -0.303131
# or this is a slightly faster
> with(dat, `-`(Table_1, Table_2)[Result == "Outlier"])
# [1] -0.731485 -0.303131
```

where `dat` is

```
dat <- read.table(h=T, text = "   Table_1 Table_2  Result
 1 5.778986    5.58  Normal
 2 5.768515    6.50 Outlier
 3 5.758068    5.83  Normal
 4 5.747644    5.54  Normal
 5 5.737245    5.80  Normal
 6 5.726869    6.03 Outlier")
```

And just for fun,

```
> f <- function() { indx <- dat$Result=="Outlier"; dat[indx,1]-dat[indx,2] }
> g <- function() with(dat, (Table_1 - Table_2)[Result == "Outlier"])
> h <- function() diff(t(dat[dat$Result == "Outlier", 2:1]))
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(f(), g(), h())
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr     min       lq   median       uq     max neval
#   f() 124.805 127.3015 132.4280 136.0405 250.500   100
#   g()  50.520  54.1260  58.4065  60.6255  84.571   100
#   h() 326.120 333.1870 350.0605 362.5885 448.587   100
```

Comment: I did a microbenchmark on a bigger dataset (1e6 rows), and didn't find much difference between f() and g() (around 124 vs 112)  etc...

Comment: @DavidArenburg Well it is easy to read and makes good sense.  A lot of people prefer readable code that makes sense over speed.  And others only have small data sets and I/we presume they always have 100 million rows.  Haha